# how to get element from multidimensional array in smarty

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty, smarty2

I have multidimensional array...

```
Array (2)
1 => Array (1)
  Body => Array (4)
    1 => "Color"
    3 => "Metal-Parts"
    4 => "Accessories"
    5 => "Materials"
2 => Array (1)
  Interieur => Array (1)
    2 => "Inner-Bags"
```

and i want to get result like this

```
> Body
    > Color
    > Metal-Parts
    > Accessories
    > Materials
> Interieur 
    >Inner-Bags
```

But i don't find the result and i am using this code..

```
[{assign var="labelarr" value=$myParam}]

[{foreach from=$labelarr key=key item=item}]

[{foreach from=$item[1] key=key1 item=item1}] 

     <h2>[{$key1}]</h2>   

[{/foreach}]

[{/foreach}]
```

But, i get the result in the like this..Only print

> Body

So please help me..
Thanks....

Comment: that's because you are printing only key1 (body)...

Comment: So which variable put insted of 'from=$item[1]'. pleas tell me...Thanks...

Comment: You have accepted the only answer.. didn't that solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
{foreach from=$labelarr key='label_key' item='label'}
   > {$label_key}
   {foreach from=$label item='label_child'}
     > {$label_child}
   {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```